# H2 ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN BEFORE/AFTER

Tags: alter-table, h2

According to H2 syntax documentation [available here](http://www.h2database.com/html/grammar.html#alter_table_add) I should be able to execute a query like:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD COLUMN SECOND_NAME VARCHAR (124) AFTER FIRST_NAME;
```

However apparently only this query works:

```
ALTER TABLE EMPLOYEE ADD COLUMN SECOND_NAME VARCHAR (124);
```

Is it a mistake in the documentation or am I missing something?
The BEFORE and AFTER parameters would be useful to me.

Comment: The order of the columns in a relational table is irrelevant. Just change them in your SELECT statements.

Comment: I know it is irrelevant in practice but in the documentation they have put this possibility for a reason. In my case it is that we often print the schema to paper and want some order for readability reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me. The H2 change log says it was added in version 1.3.171. Here is the original [bug](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/issues/detail?id=401)

```
alter table credentials add column domain VARCHAR(255) after credentialType;
```

What didn't work for me was having multiple `adds` inside one `alter`.